# Access 2007: DLookup for Autofill not returning values

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Developing a database for visually impaired persons scheduling donation pickups (uses an audio reader for fields).  Have a simple table " Truck_Routes" with customer ID, street address, suite, company, city, state, zip, contact name, contact phone number, and several donation information fields.

Trying to develop a form that auto fills: suite, company, city, state, zip, contact name, and contact phone number based on an existing combo box: cboAddress ....(street address).   Spent hours on the web emulating other examples, but can't get vba to work.

Street Address - combo box with "After_Update event procedure"

```
Private Sub cboAddress_AfterUpdate()
  PopulateFields
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateFields()
  Me.Suite = DLookup("Suite", "Truck_Routes", "Street Address=" & Me.[cboAddress & "'"])
  Me.Company = DLookup("Company", "Truck_Routes", "Street Address=" & Me.[cboAddress & "'"])
  Me.City = DLookup("City ", "Truck_Routes", "Street Address=" & Me.[cboAddress & "'"])
  Me.State = DLookup("State ", "Truck_Routes", "Street Address=" & Me.[cboAddress & "'"])
  Me.zip = DLookup("zip ", "Truck_Routes", "Street Address=" & Me.[cboAddress & "'"])
  Me.ContactName = DLookup("ContactName ", "Truck_Routes", "Street Address=" & Me.[cboAddress & "'"])
  Me.ContactPHone = DLookup("ContactPhone ", "Truck_Routes", "Street Address=" & Me.[cboAddress & "'"])
End Sub
```

Fields in form are navigated using "tab" key, audio reader reads the field.  Default value for each field is the name of the field so it could be read to the operator.  Any thoughts/recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your DLookup a bit off, the square brackets are outside the quotes. Also they are supposed to be enclosed inside single quotes, as they are Text types. I have fixed them for you.

```
Private Sub cboAddress_AfterUpdate()
    PopulateFields
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateFields()
    Me.Suite = DLookup("Suite", "Truck_Routes", "[Street Address] = '" & Me.cboAddress & "'")
    Me.Company = DLookup("Company", "Truck_Routes", "[Street Address] = '" & Me.cboAddress & "'")
    Me.City = DLookup("City ", "Truck_Routes", "[Street Address] = '" & Me.cboAddress & "'")
    Me.State = DLookup("State ", "Truck_Routes", "[Street Address] = '" & Me.cboAddress & "'")
    Me.zip = DLookup("zip ", "Truck_Routes", "[Street Address] = '" & Me.cboAddress & "'")
    Me.ContactName = DLookup("ContactName ", "Truck_Routes", "[Street Address] = '" & Me.cboAddress & "'")
    Me.ContactPHone = DLookup("ContactPhone ", "Truck_Routes", "[Street Address] = '" & Me.cboAddress & "'")
End Sub
```

On a side note, the Domain function is rather expensive piece of operation. It is a simplified SQL. So every time you use a DLookup, you are performing a READ to the table in the above example you are querying the table 7 times, in one single AfterUpdate. This could be massively reduced if you were to use a RecordSet object.

Something like,

```
Private Sub cboAddress_AfterUpdate()
    PopulateFields
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateFields()
    Dim rsObj As DAO.Recordset

    Set rsObj = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT Suite, Company, City, State, zip, ContactName, ContactPhone " & _
                                    "FROM Truck_Routes WHERE [Street Address] = '" & Me.cboAddress & "'")

    If Not rsObj.EOF Then
        Me.Suite = rsObj.Fields("Suite")
        Me.Company = rsObj.Fields("Company")
        Me.City = rsObj.Fields("City")
        Me.State = rsObj.Fields("State")
        Me.zip = rsObj.Fields("zip")
        Me.ContactName = rsObj.Fields("ContactName")
        Me.ContactPHone = rsObj.Fields("ContactPhone")
    Else
        MsgBox "No Information matched."
    End If

    Set rsObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

There are also other advantages like,

1. Checking if the Recordset returns more than one row using the **RecordCount** property of the RecordSet object.
2. This not only reduces the hit on the Database, this code also cleans up after itself unlike a Domain function.

Hope this helps !

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314516/access-2007-dlookup-for-autofill-not-returning-values)  PaulFrancis....thank you so much.  I used the code, but got an Compile Error: Expected Function or variable at "Set rsObj = CurrentDb.Execute" ..."Execute" was highlighted...

Comment: Sorry @Michael, I used `Execute` where I should have use **OpenRecordset** I have edited my answer.

Comment: Seems his table includes a field whose name includes a space, *Street Address*.  Enclose that name in square brackets so the db engine will recognize it correctly: `WHERE [Street Address] = ` Note that issue also applies to the `DLookup` approach.

Comment: Are you saying a domain function does not "clean up after itself"?  What does that mean?

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314516/access-2007-dlookup-for-autofill-not-returning-values)  PaulFrancis...thank you for the update.    I created the Street Address as a combo box with only the street address in the lookup table.  When the volunteer enters a new record (Ctr+Shf++) the street address field "highlights" and reads aloud "street address."  The worker can then put in the address.  (cont.)

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314516/access-2007-dlookup-for-autofill-not-returning-values) ...(cont)  If it matches one in the table, it will continue to read out the whole address.  When the match is audibly identified the worker hits "Tab key" where I want the remaining fields to auto populate.  I input the code and executed.  Got the message: "no information matched."   However, the "Truck_Routes" table does have an exact match (record ID # 8) and all other fields (suite, city, zip, contact, phone) are filled, yet it will not populate the form...